# WCF Default Endpoint Missing

Tags: wcf, iis-7

I am deploying a WCF Service to IIS 7 and when I navigate to the service URL I get a page like this:

[image: Service Landing Page]

I do not get the typical landing page like this (copied from the web just to show example, data blurred to protect the innocent):

[image]

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?  The service works as expected but there is nothing for a user of this service to view to know what the methods are or where to get the WSDL.

Here are my relevant files:

**App.Config** (in service project and copied to service site as Web.Config for IIS)

```
 <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MyService.MyService" behaviorConfiguration="Web">
        <clear />

        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  name="ws"
                  behaviorConfiguration="Web"
                      contract="MyService.IMyService" />
<!--           
            <endpoint address="" 
                  behaviorConfiguration="Web" 
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="" 
                  name="web" 
                  contract="MyService.IMyService" />
--> 

        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://services.mydomain.com/MyService" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>

      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Web">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Web">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**MyService.svc**

```
<%@ ServiceHost Service="MyService.MyService"
                Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory" %>
```

I also tried using 'webHttpBinding' instead of 'wsHttpBinding' and it didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: When you say you copied app.config, you renamed it to web.config for IIS, right?

Comment: Yes I did, good catch (have updated the post to indicate this).

Comment: Can't see anything obviously wrong, did you try a deliberate syntax error in web.config so that you can make sure it's being read from that location?

Comment: Is the service's fully qualified name "MyService.MyService" ?

Comment: I did try deliberately messing up the Web.Config file and it does then throw an error so I am sure the file is reading from where I think it is.

Comment: The service namespace is simply 'MyService' and the public class is 'MyService' so I am pretty sure the fully qualified name is 'MyService.MyService' unless I am missing something.  Like I said the program works as expected (am able to call methods) it is just this landing page that doesn't display correctly.

Comment: The service config shows will not work as you would get a failure because of the webHttpBehavior being used with wsHttpBinding. If you remove that attribute does it make any difference?

Comment: Removing the behavior didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

ServiceHost Service="MyService.MyService" ... is this line correct?

Comment: It is correct.  It is a reference to the name space and class as it is imported into this project as a DLL.